# How can I pass a property as a parameter without passing the property name as a string in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties

I want to access a property inside another method **without** passing the property name as a string. There are two reasons for this requirement:

1. I cannot pass the property value, as I may not want to evaluate it, but retrieve it from a cache instead (the cache will be more efficient in my setup, for some properties).
2. I do not want to pass the name as a string because compile-time errors will not be raised if the string is invalid.

After hours of searching, I have not found a definite answer (which makes me wonder if one exists!). I have explored the following options so far:

- Using **ByRef** - This does not give the ability to access the property name.
- Using **Reflection** - This would need to have the property name passed in as a string, which I want to avoid (from [Alois at GeeksWithBlogs (via the Internet Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221092055/geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/02/10/69047.aspx)).
- Using **Delegation** - This looked like the most likely method, but properties are not supported (from [a thread at Extreme.NetTalk](https://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/threads/assigning-a-delegate-to-a-property.96800/)).

Below is an oversimplified demonstration of how I would implement this if properties could be used in delegation:

```
Delegate Property FunctionName() As String

Public Function GetPropName(ByVal prop As FunctionName) As String
    Return prop.Method.Name
End Function

Public Sub Test()
    Dim x As New MyType()
    ' This should print 'Definition'
    Debug.Print(GetPropName(AddressOf x.Definition))
End Sub
```

Is there a way to pass a property as a parameter - in a format which allows access to both its name and value - without passing the property name as a string?

Comment: Why do you care about the name?  Surely all that matters is that you can get the property value when you need it and not when you call the method.  You can do what you want as far as the property value but I'm not sure if it gives you access to the property name.  Such methods are used commonly in ASP.NET MVC, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703644%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Can you pass a System.Reflection.PropertyInfo? From that you can get the property name.

Comment: @DanVerdolino To use this I would still need to use a string: `obj.GetType.GetProperty("Definition")`

Comment: @jmcilhinney I need the name of the property to know what I'm looking for in the cache. I access each item in the cache using the property name and an object identifier.

Comment: The first link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to *[Geekswithblogs.net, the End of an Era](http://julian.farm/geekswithblogs/?url=/mtreadwell/archive/2004/06/06/6123.aspx)*.

Comment: I've replaced it with a link to the archived page, thanks.